# How do I silence confint in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm looping through many analyses in an R notebook, and capturing confidence intervals each iteration. Each time, confint emits "Waiting for profiling to be done..." as output that shows up in the notebook. Can I suppress this?

The following code emits the message I'd like to avoid in the console and RStudio. If it matters, I only care about the output to the notebook in RStudio.

```
y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
x = c(2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8,2,4)
fit = glm(y ~ x)
ci.05 = confint(fit, level=0.95)["x","2.5 %"]
print(paste("The lower bound of the 95% CI is",ci.05))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@mko's solution is a nice general way to attack problems like these but in this particular case you can get rid of the message by passing a profile object to `confint` directly.  If you use the following line instead of your original code none of the output will be any different but you won't get the message that is annoying you.

```
ci.05 = confint(profile(fit), level=0.95)["x","2.5 %"]
```

Comment: Very helpful. This answer seems to be a more direct solution to my problem than suppressMessages(). Do you know if calling profile explicitly like this is faster, slower, stylistically better, etc? I ignorantly assume confint is just calling profile behind the scenes and doing exactly the same thing, but with a message to say so?

Comment: It's not something I typically do but the documentation led me to try that to see if it would get rid of the message.  It does look like confint does just call profile for glms and gives you that message.  I don't really think the speed difference will be anything to worry about (unless you're doing something like a simulation and replicating this thousands/millions of times - but even then I don't know if you gain much).  The main benefits of being explicit like this are 1) you don't get the message printed to the console and 2) you get more control over the profiling if you want to.

Comment: I've recently found, after clearing my environment and restarting everything, that I get the error - Error in UseMethod("profile") : no applicable method for 'profile' applied to an object of class "c('glm','lm')" when I run this code. But after doing a confint(fit), the profile works fine. Any idea why profile doesn't work the first time out?

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
suppressMessages(confint(fit, level=0.95)["x","2.5 %"])
```